# command works in terminal and not in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The bellow commands works in terminal and prints value 1

```
count_XXX=`ll -d /usr/Systems/XXX* 2> /dev/null | grep ^d | wc -l`
echo "$count_XXX"
```

There is one directory and two softlinks in the directory /usr/Systems with the same name XXX*.

when i keep the same two lines in shell script. It prints value 0

This works fine in unix(both terminal and script) but when i try to run in linux server the issue happens(in script).

do i need to change something for Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ll` is not a command, it's an alias so you should probably be using `ls`. Might be that the alias doesn't exist on your linux system

Comment: @arco444 it works on terminal.so i see the alias works

Comment: Doesn't matter, would strongly advise you not to use it. There are all sorts of situations where aliases may not get loaded. Much safer to use the command directly. Would probably be `ls -alFd` in this case

Comment: Yes.. Thanks it worked.
due to "2> /dev/null" i am not able see the error message.
it is ll not found

Answer (score 2):

Using `ll` then `grep` and then `wc` is bit too much for counting directories and this is also error prone due to possibility of whitespace/newline in directory names.

In BASH use this simple snippet:

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( /usr/Systems/XXX*/ )
echo ${#arr[@]}
2
```

- `/` at the end of your glob pattern makes sure it matches only directories.
- `shopt -s nullglob` to make sure to not to print pattern when glob pattern doesn't match anything

Comment: it returns 1 if nothing exists also..? how to take the value in to variablle.

Comment: To store in a variable just use: `count=${#arr[@]}` above

Comment: I am checking on it. Thanks